# Transforming a set of equations from one set of variables to another?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n$ are $n$ positive numbers such that $$\theta_1+\dots+\theta_n=1$$ Define $y_{ij}=\frac{\theta_i}{\theta_j}$ for all $i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Is there a way to transform the above equation in terms of $y_{ij}$.

Comment: The fact that the left-hand side is of degree $1$ (in the $\theta$) while both the right-hand side and $y_{ij}$ are of degree $0$ might make this very difficult.

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use $\theta_i = \theta_j y_{ij}$ to write $\theta_1+\theta_2\dots+\theta_n=1$ as $\theta_j y_{1j}+\theta_j y_{2j}+\dots+ \theta_j y_{nj}= 1$

Collect $\theta_j$ s.t. $\theta_j(y_{1j}+y_{2j}+\dots+y_{nj})= 1$ so $\theta_j = \displaystyle \frac{1}{y_{1j}+y_{2j}+\dots+y_{nj}}=\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{kj}}$

$\theta_1+\theta_2\dots+\theta_n=1 = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{k1}}  + \frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{k2}} + \dots+\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{kn}} = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{kj}}$

---

Edit 2

More simply:

Given
$$\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \dots+ \theta_‌​n= 1$$
$$\theta_j > 0$$
$$y_{ij} = \frac{\theta_i}{\theta_j}$$
then
$$ \theta_j = \displaystyle \frac{\theta_j}{\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \dots+ \theta_‌​n} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_j}+\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_j}+\dots+\frac{\theta_‌​‌​n}{\theta_j}} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{y_{1j}+y_{2j}+\dots+y_{nj}}$$
Or
$$ y_{1j}+y_{2j}+\dots+y_{nj} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\theta_j}$$
So each $\theta_j$ is reduced to a $y_{kj}$ expression.

So any expression written in $\theta_j$ variables can be transformed into an expression in $y_{kj}$ variables.

Comment: This condition ($\sum\limits_j(1/\sum\limits_k y_{kj}) =1$) is satisfied for ARBITRARY non-zero $\theta_i$: $\sum\limits_j(1/\sum\limits_k y_{kj}) = \sum\limits_j (\sum\limits_k \frac{\theta_k}{\theta_j})^{-1} = \sum\limits_j (\frac{\sum\limits_k \theta_k}{\theta_j})^{-1} =  \sum\limits_j \frac{\theta_j}{\sum\limits_k \theta_k} = \frac{\sum\limits_j \theta_j}{\sum\limits_k \theta_k} = 1$

Comment: Yes I agree. That's interesting. The key relationship is:
$$\theta_j = \displaystyle \frac{1}{y_{1j}+y_{2j}+\dots+y_{nj}} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_j}+\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_j}+\dots+\frac{\theta_‌​n}{\theta_j}}=\displaystyle \frac{\theta_j}{\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \dots+ \theta_‌​n} = \theta_j$$ This only holds for $\theta_1+\theta_2\dots+\theta_n=1$

Comment: @arthur Isn't the additional conditions , $y_{ij}\geq 0 $ and $y_{ij}y_{ji}=1$ also needed?

Comment: @dineshdileep Yes. $\theta_j \gt 0$ (positive numbers) so $y_{ij} \gt 0$. $y_{ij}y_{ji}=1$ follows from the definition of  $y_{ij} $

Answer (score 5):

No. If you multiply all $\theta_i$ by the same positive number $c\neq 1$, then all $y_{ij}$ stay the same, but $\theta_1+\dots+\theta_n$ changes.

In more details: assume that you have a condition or a set of conditions on $y_{ij}=\frac{\theta_i}{\theta_j}$ which is satisfied if and only if $\theta_1+\dots+\theta_n=1$. Let $\overline{\theta}_i$ be positive numbers such that $\overline{\theta}_1+\dots+\overline{\theta}_n=1$. Then, by assumption, the numbers $\overline{y}_{ij}=\frac{\overline{\theta}_i}{\overline{\theta}_j}$ satisfy that condition(s). Now choose a positive number $c\neq 1$ and set $\theta'_i = c\overline{\theta}_i$. Then $y'_{ij} = \frac{\theta'_i}{\theta'_j} = \overline{y}_{ij}$, so the numbers $y'_{ij}$ satisfy the condition(s) as well, but $\theta'_1+\dots+\theta'_n = c(\overline{\theta}_1+\dots+\overline{\theta}_n) = c\neq 1$.

Comment: but $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_i'\neq 1$??

Comment: @dineshdileep Yes? That's the whole point: you cannot find condition(s) on $y_{ij}$ that would be satisfied ONLY if $\sum\theta_i = 1$.

Comment: No, I meant why should $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_i'\,=\,1$?. You didn't pick them like that. So there is nothing contradicting. You just defined $\theta_i'=c\bar{\theta_i}$. That doesn't imply they should sum to 1.

Comment: @dineshdileep Yes, I intentionally defined them in such a way that $\sum\theta'_i\neq 1$. Maybe I misunderstand your original question: when you write "Is there a way to transform the above equation in terms of $y_{ij}$", what equation do you mean? That $\sum\theta_i = 1$?

Comment: yes. Like the other answer tries to do.

Comment: @dineshdileep Then it means that you want some condition(s) on $y_{ij}$ which would be satisfied when $\sum\theta_i=1$ and would NOT be satisfied when $\sum\theta_i\neq 1$, right? So that, even if you know just $y_{ij}$ and don't know $\theta_i$, you could tell whether $\sum\theta_i=1$ or not.

Comment: exactly. Conditions on $y_{ij}$ should translate to conditions on $\theta_i$.

Comment: @dineshdileep And I explain in the answer that this is impossible. The same $y_{ij}$ correspond to both $\overline{\theta}_i$ and $\theta'_i$, even though $\sum\overline{\theta}_i =1$ and $\sum\theta'_i\neq 1$. So, looking at just $y_{ij}$, you cannot tell whether $\sum\theta_i=1$ or not.

Comment: Please look at this problem when there are only $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$

Comment: @dineshdileep Consider even more specific case: when $y_{12}=y_{21}=1$. Can you tell whether $\theta_1+\theta_2=1$? No, all you know is that $\theta_1=\theta_2$. They may be equal to $0.5$, and then their sum _is_ equal to $1$; but they may be equal to any other positive number as well, and then their sum is different.

Comment: But you also have the conditions, $\theta_1=\frac{1}{y_{11}+y_{12}}$ and $\theta_2=\frac{1}{y_{21}+y_{22}}$, so you have what you expect, just like the other answer says.

Comment: @dineshdileep You have these conditions only if you _already know_ that $\theta_1+\theta_2=1$. And if you already know it, you don't need to look at $y_{ij}$ to say whether it's true or not.